# Hardware for virtualization

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, hardware

I need to choose appropriate hardware for virtualize with vmware
- 1 windows server 2016 (active directory, wsus, centralized antivirus software...)
- 1 windows server 2008 (run 2 server software)
- 1 pfsense (openvpn only)
- 1 linux server machine (cacti, loganalyzer)

For the host machine I can shoose between:
1 x 8 core Xeon Silver 4110 2.1 GHz - 16 GB RAM;
2 x 8 core Xeon Silver 4110 2.1 GHz - 16 GB RAM;
1 x 10 core Xeon Gold 5115 - 32 GB RAM;
2 x 8 core Xeon E5-2670 - 48 GB RAM;

What can I choose with the minimum requirement? Is the first sufficient?

Comment: It depends on many factors but 16GB of RAM sounds way too little. Also, is this for a lab setup or production and if the latter, how many users are there in the organization?

Comment: We'll need more information to help you out here. Please be aware that you and your team are the only people who can answer this finally since we can never know your whole requirements and all the factors in play. This being said, 16GB RAM seems too little for what you're attempting.